# Generating two random coordinates in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I intended to output the following in a Windows batch file to print five random coordinates wihtin a given range. I know this task is easier on other languages but I'm forced to use Windows batch programming.

**INTENDED OUTPUT:**

```
x1:1344
y1:1995
x1:1347
y1:1998
x1:1350
y1:1996
x1:1345
y1:1999
x1:1345
y1:1995
)
```

My windows batch coding is not that great and I complied the following using Google Fu.
I'm not sure what I'm missing but the following code is supposed to output two random numbers as a coordinate (x1 and y1).
However my code below does not give me my intended output

**CODE**

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%a in (1 1 5) do (
        REM Random X coordinate between 1336 1350)       
        call:rand 1336 1350      
        set /A x1= !RAND_NUM!        
        echo(!x1!)

        REM Random Y coordinate between 1950 2000)
        call:rand 1950 2000
        set /A y1= !RAND_NUM!
        echo(!y1!)
)

goto:EOF

:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto:EOF
```

My output is missing the five y coordinates and prints the first five x coordinates first and then one y coordinate and stops.

**OUTPUT:**

```
x1:1344
x1:1349
x1:1347
x1:1342
x1:1347
y1:1995)
```

Answer (score 2):

The closing parenthesis `)` inside of the code block is seen as the closing parenthesis of the code block itself, if you really needed them, which you don't you would need to escape them `^)` but instead remove them entirely. Also no need to `set /A` `x1` and `y1` just `set` can work on its own, but even that `set` is not needed:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%a in (1 1 5) do (
        REM Random X coordinate between 1336 1350
        call:rand 1336 1350           
        echo(x1:!RAND_NUM!

        REM Random Y coordinate between 1950 2000
        call:rand 1950 2000
        echo(y1:!RAND_NUM!
)
goto:EOF

:rand
set /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Ahh...I see it now. I just had to remove the parenthesis around the echo(!x1!) and echo(!y1!), and now it works like a charm. I put those in previously because I used to get some Missing Operand error , but that problem has also vanished. Thanks Boss!